# Why firefox behaves so weirdly/annoying?

Tags: firefox, freeze, cpu-usage, io

Occasionally FF starts very heavy activities, performing huge amounts of I/O (On my HDD) and considerable CPU usage for a long time (More than 10 minutes is really normal for it) that there is no apparent reason for it and can't be stopped easily. In the meanwhile my PC gets very slow and Firefox itself almost hangs. Very frustrating!

It continues even after closing Firefox for quite a while.

FF really behaves like a heavy antivirus program while performing a full HDD scan!!

I am using FFv60 on Windows7, but have experienced the same problem on other PCs with different FF versions and OSes.

Comment: I wonder if you have a hard disk and your FF is swapping?

Comment: How much RAM does your computer have?

Comment: @Mokubai I have 4 GB of RAM

Comment: What sites are you visiting when this happens? Does it only happen when you visit specific site or it is *every* site?

Comment: @Mokubai, no it isn't site specific.

Comment: Check in Resource Monitor what is running at that time. Also check the Memory tab. If most memory is allocated, the HDD memory swapping activity may account for what is happening.